# How trivial is it to derive a private key from two public keys?

Tags: public-key, dsa

It turns out that what I was attempting to do was create a form of ECDSA threshold signature protocol by just giving away multiple public keys and then having the two parties solve for the private.

---

**Original Question**

I am currently working on building an application and I have a question about the triviality of deriving private keys from multiple public keys. I have read many places that it is possible to derive multiple public keys from a single private key but that publicly revealing more than one will jeopardize the private keys security. If I want to produce two public keys from a single private key (ECDSA) and derive the private key later using only the public keys, how much does knowing the two public keys help. Will two public keys easily yield a single private key? Will introducing more than two public keys reduce the amount of computation that it takes to derive a private key if it is computational difficult?

Comment: I guess you meant _"that it is possible to derive multiple **public** keys from a single private key but that publicly revealing more than one will jeopardize the private **key's** security"_. Please give a link to where that is explained, as it I fail to understand what is meant, especially in an ECDSA context.

Comment: [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9375044/can-we-have-multiple-public-keys-with-a-single-private-key-for-rsa), [Link](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/10728/can-an-rsa-private-key-have-several-public-keys) does this only apply to trap doors like RSA? That may be where I am misunderstanding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Responding to comment-implied intended question**:

The RSA alternative public keys revealing the secret factors of $N$ is not a suitable means to implement threshold protocols. Instead you should be using actual threshold protocols, such as t-of-n or n-of-n signature schemes.

ECDSA uses DSA, not Schnorr, so my [usual suggestions](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/57640/56625) do not apply. Although a quick search for "threshold dsa" yields:

[Securing Bitcoin wallets via a new DSA/ECDSA threshold signature scheme](https://www.cs.princeton.edu/~stevenag/threshold_sigs.pdf)

---

**Old answer (kept for alternative interest)**

This sounds like key-blinding, where you derive a subkey from a master pair. Say you have the secret key $k$, public key $Gk$ and the blinding factor $b$, the subkey secret is $kb$ and the subkey public is $Gkb$.

$Gkb$ and $Gk$ cannot be used to recover $k$ nor $b$, without breaking Diffie-Hellman. $b$ may be derived from $Gk$ plus some contextual string, this allows someone with the master public and master secret to compute the subkeys respectively. These keys are tightly related, given $kb$ and $b$, you can recover $k$. If you give someone $kb$ but keep $b$ secret, they cannot recover $k$. If $kb = k * b$ then $k = kb / b$.

If deriving a subkey from a public key gave you any information useful to recover the secret key, the scheme is broken with only one public key.

Comment: I have removed all the comments here (it were like 20), as the question and answer seem clarified now. If any particular info from the now removed comments is needed, ping me with @SEJPM and I shall restore it (I didn't move to chat because Adam can't chat yet).

Comment: [You may be interested in this 2017 paper by Lindell on fast two-party ECDSA threshold signing.](https://eprint.iacr.org/2017/552)